# Union of multiple K-minimum values sets of different sizes in the KMV algorithm

Tags: algorithm, distributed-system, distinct-values

While researching the K-minimum values (KVM) method I've found the following paragraph in the blog on KMV method:

> Note that if the two KMV objects are of different size, due to K being
>   different sizes, or because either one isn't completely filled with K minimum values, you should use the smaller value of K as your union set K size.

and also

> To perform union, you merely take 2 sketches and combine their values and keep the k smallest ones (if the 2 sketches are of different sizes, k and k', then you keep the min(k,k') values in order to keep the lowest resolution).

Then it seems that if I am trying to use large K (for better accuracy, e.g. 2048) then if I look at the multiple KMV objects (e.g. tables in databases reporting unique users of the internet portal) and even one of them has less distinct values than K (i.e. K'), then I would have to use that smaller value of K' in the final union. Instead of large K, I may end up with very small K'. May I simply ignore the fact that K' < K and use K minimum values each time I combine the minimum value data sets? Or better question would be: what is wrong with simply using K in all cases and why we need to use the smaller value?

Answer (score 4):

KMV is [commonly formulated](https://datasketches.apache.org/docs/Theta/KMVbetterEst.html#:%7E:text=The%20fractional%20distance%20that%20these,as%20a%20Bottom%2Dk%20sketch.) as taking the smallest k hashes of a dataset for some fixed k and estimating cardinality as (k-1) * (# of all possible hashes) / (largest hash value).

A clearer way to think about it is that you're taking all the hashes that are in some range (for unsigned hash values, generally between 0 and some threshold). Your estimate is the number of hashes you get adjusted for what proportion of the total range of hashes is included in your range i.e. (# of kept hashes) * (# of all possible hashes) / (# of possible hashes in your range). It operates under the assumption that the hash function distributes hashes uniformly at random among all the possible hashes. Implementation-wise, you store the threshold alongside the hashes in your KMV data structure.

As described in [this (I think overly verbose) paper](https://github.com/apache/datasketches-website/blob/master/docs/pdf/ThetaSketchFramework.pdf), KMV is a special case of this where you choose your threshold to be the kth largest value and every time you add a value that's below your threshold, you lower your threshold so that you keep the size of your data constant, discarding the largest hash. The estimate for KMV is given by (k-1) * (# of all possible hashes) / (largest hash value) because your threshold is the largest hash value (so your hash range is between 0 and the largest hash value, so the size of your range is the largest hash value) and there were k-1 hashes smaller than that threshold.

When implementing unions, intersections, differences, or any other set operations, you need the thresholds of the operands to match (which you can achieve by lowering the threshold of the one with the higher threshold to match the lower threshold, discarding any hashes which exceed the new threshold). Then the result is just the set of hashes that are the union/intersection/difference of the hashes of the operands with the threshold that is what they both have as a threshold.

Put back in terms of the common formulation of KMV, to perform a union, you union the sets of hashes then remove any hashes that are larger than the smaller of the maxima of the operands. Whatever number of elements you end up with is the k of your result. For unions, k will be at least as large as that of the operands - you're free to remove elements until k is back down to that of the operands if you wish (this is equivalent to using the smaller of the k's as the k of your result). For intersections, k will be at most as large as that of the operands - if it's lower, unfortunately the precision of your cardinality estimate will be lower.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the KMV sketch to work, you need the k minimum values. If one of the branches of the union didn't have k values to begin with, you can still take the union and truncate to k. It's only if you truncate to k' that you have to truncate the combined sketch to k'.

In fact, you can use even more of the samples to improve accuracy. See https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0625 *, which shows that it suffices to discard only down to the min discarded sample (which may be nothing at all), resulting in slightly better accuracy.

* Leveraging Discarded Samples for Tighter Estimation of Multiple-Set Aggregates. Edith Cohen, Haim Kaplan.